# Get 9am unix timestamp in python

Tags: python, datetime

If I want to know the the timestamp for the next day 9am of the system,

There could be two cases:

```
1. If the current time is 11 P.M of 2013-11-05 and I want to get the timestamp for 9 A.M 2013-11-06

2. If the current time is 2 A.M for 2013-11-06 and I need the timestamp for 9 A.M for same day
```

Is there a better way to handle this or I calculate my hours, day, month , year separately and then generate a datetime object which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems pretty simple. Check the time; if it's less than 09:00 then just set the time values with `replace`. If it's greater, add `datetime.timedelta(hours=24)` and do the same thing.

Comment: If current time is 11 A.M then adding datetime.timedelta(hours=24) would give me time for next day 11 A.M

Comment: @jdk2588, but then setting the time values would make it the next day 9 AM which is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: @jdk2588 This ignores times where adding 24 hours won't give you the next day, e.g DST ending, leap seconds. So while it may work for 9am, it won't work for any given time of day.

Comment: @agf, the `datetime` module has no notion of leap seconds, and unless you go out of your way to attach a `tzinfo` field, no notion of time zones or "daylight"/"standard" times either.  Excepting the latter, Mark's suggestion will always give "the next 9am".  The only change I'd make to that is to add `timedelta(days=1)` instead (for a teensy improvement in clarity).